# angular2 Form Value on Set and Disable not binding data

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Here is my oode to update the Form if user is available.

```
if (this.user.landmark) this.uploadForm.controls['landmark'].setValue(this.user.landmark || '');
    //if (this.user.landmark) this.uploadForm.get('landmark').disable({ onlySelf: true });
```

If i uncomment disable, and click on submit, the landmark field is not generated in the output json.

**For Example**

Without Disable

console.log(this.uploadForm.value) gives

```
{
username:"dummyUser",
landmark:"Nearby EB Office"
}
```

With Disable

console.log(this.uploadForm.value) gives

```
{
username:"dummyUser"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`FormGroup.value` doesn't include controls that are disabled

```typescript
 it('should ignore disabled controls when serializing value in a group', () => {
    const c = new FormControl('one');
    const c2 = new FormControl('two');
    const g = new FormGroup({one: c, two: c2});
    expect(g.value).toEqual({one: 'one', two: 'two'});

    c.disable();
    expect(g.value).toEqual({two: 'two'});

    c.enable();
    expect(g.value).toEqual({one: 'one', two: 'two'});
  });
```

Use `this.uploadForm.getRawValue()` instead. See also [doc](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue)

> If you'd like to include all values regardless of disabled status, use
>   this method. Otherwise, the value property is the best way to get the
>   value of the group.